# How to use smo to restore database from other computer in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

how to use smo to restore database from other computer in c#? This is my resource:

```
private void btnrestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (srv != null)
            {
                ofd.Title = "Restore BackUp...";
                ofd.Filter = "Backup File|*.bak";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Restore re_db = new Restore();
                    re_db.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
                    re_db.Database = cmbDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    BackupDeviceItem bk_item = new BackupDeviceItem(ofd.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                    re_db.Devices.Add(bk_item);
                    re_db.ReplaceDatabase = true;
                    re_db.SqlRestore(srv);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A connection to a SQL server was not established.", "Not Connected to Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I want to remote to other computer by "OpenFileDialog".

Comment: So what is happening (or not happening?)  Are you getting an error?    What error?  Where is it happening?

Comment: Is the problem with not being able to access the other computer with `OpenFileDialog`, or with the actual restore once you have obtained the file name and path?

Comment: On file explorer, type \\machinename then you will be able to reach shared file folders on the computer or type \\machinename\c$ then it will ask you for credentals

Answer (score 0):

Late but not too late, heck out this page
http://www.mssqltips.com/tipprint.asp?tip=1849